# Returning a success message from multiple queries if not all are run

Tags: php

I have 4 queries inside one function, this is to nsert to create a resume. This includes education, employment, skills and the main CV to join them.

Now when they're creating a CV they won't always fill out all the different forms to create the above stuff (education, work, skills) but I need to return 1 success message. I can't use an if else: on the rowcount because that would return a value for all of them or none, so how can I echo:

```
Alert::success('adding_resume', true);
```

once even if the forms empty on some of them;

```
public static function create_resume()
{

    // Let's define the rules and filters
    $rules = array(
        'resume_title'    => 'max_len,100|required',
        'expected_level'    => 'max_len,100|required',
        'expected_salary'    => 'required|max_len,12|integer',
        'work_location'    => 'max_len,100',
        'year_experience'    => 'max_len,100|integer'
    );


    //validate the info
    $validated = FormValidation::is_valid($_POST, $rules);

    // Check if validation was successful
    if($validated !== TRUE):    

        //exit with an error
        exit(Alert::error(false, true, $validated));

    endif;

    //initate db
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();


    //sql to run
    $sql = "INSERT INTO resumes
            (
                resume_title,
                resume_work_level,
                resume_total_work_experience,
                resume_salary,
                resume_work_country,
                resume_about,
                resume_user,
                resume_date_created
            )
            VALUES
            (
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?
            )"; 

    //run the sql
    $resume = $database->prepare($sql);
    $resume->execute(array(Request::post('resume_title'), Request::post('expected_level'), Request::post('year_experience'), 
                        Request::post('expected_salary'), Request::post('work_location'), Request::post('about'), Session::get('id'),
                        date("Y-m-d")));


    //results?
    if($resume->rowCount())
    {

        //resume id
        $resume_id = $database->lastinsertid();

        //create employment
        $sql_employment = "INSERT INTO employment
                           (
                                employment_company,
                                employment_name,
                                employment_datestart,
                                employment_dateend,
                                employment_description,
                                employment_country,
                                employment_user,
                                employment_resume
                           )
                           VALUES
                           (
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?,
                                ?
                           )";

        //run the sql
        $employments = $database->prepare($sql_employment);

        //if they have more than 1
        foreach($_POST['experience'] as $employment): 
            $employments->execute(array($employment['company'], $employment['title'], date("Y-m-d", strtotime($employment['year_begin'])), 
                                  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($employment['year_finish'])), $employment['notes'], $employment['country'], 
                                  Session::get('id'), $resume_id));
        endforeach; 

        if($employments->rowCount())
        {

            //sql to run
            $education_sql = "INSERT INTO education
                              (
                                    education_institute,
                                    education_degree,
                                    education_dateobtained,
                                    education_dateexpires,
                                    education_description,
                                    education_user,
                                    education_date,
                                    education_resume

                              )
                              VALUES
                              (
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?
                              )";

            //run the sql
            $educations = $database->prepare($education_sql);

            //for multiple education
            foreach(Request::post('education') as $education):
                $educations->execute(array($education['institution'], $education['degree'], date("Y-m-d", strtotime($education['year_begin'])), 
                                    date("Y-m-d", strtotime($education['year_finish'])), $education['about'], Session::get('id'), date("Y-m-d"), 
                                    $resume_id));   

            endforeach;

            //results
            if($educations->rowCount())
            {
                //sql to run
                $sql_skill = "INSERT INTO skills
                              (  
                                   skill_type,
                                   skill_percent,
                                   skill_user,
                                   skill_resume
                              )
                              VALUES
                              (
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?,
                                    ?
                              )";
                //run the sql
                $skills = $database->prepare($sql_skill);

                //for each skill
                foreach(Request::post('skill') as $skill):
                    $skills->execute(array($skill['name'], $skill['percentage'], Session::get('id'), $resume_id));
                endforeach;

                //the results?
                if($skills->rowCount())
                {
                    Alert::success('adding_resume', true);
                }else{
                    Alert::alert('adding_resume', true);
                }
            }else{
                Alert::error('adding_resume', true);
            }

        }else{
            Alert::error('adding_resume', true);
        }

    }else{
        Alert::error('adding_resume', true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like an odd way for you to go about this, just trying to insert everything without checking any of it, but you can do this:

1. Create a boolean value which is initially set to false.
2. After each query, check the result.
3. If the result is true, change your boolean variable to true. If the result is false, do NOT change the boolean variable.
4. After all queries have run, if your boolean variable is true, at least one of the queries was successful.

Example code:

```
$good_query = false;

<build sql query for resume stuff>

$check = $resume->execute(<blah>);

if ($check) { $good_query = true; }

<build sql query for employment stuff>

$check = $resume->execute(<blah>);

if ($check) { $good_query = true; }

<build sql query for education stuff>

$check = $resume->execute(<blah>);

if ($check) { $good_query = true; }

<build sql query for skills stuff>

$check = $resume->execute(<blah>);

if ($check) { $good_query = true; }
```

if $good_query is true at the end, at least one of your queries succeeded.